# Amazon Web Service (AWS) Private Storage For Authenticated Users

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, amazon-s3, firebase-storage, amazon-cognito

My Project Flow:

1. You go to my website
2. You login with Username and Password that admin made
3. You got to see your dedicated files, private to your account

I already made the basis with Firebase (`Authentication` and `Storage`). So in Firebase i made this `Storage Rules`

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /assets/{userId}/{assetsId} {
            allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Ilustration storage:

```
assets/
|----user01/
|    |----user01.jpg
|----user02/
|    |----user02.jpg
```

basically only that user01 can see user01.jpg & only that user02 can access see user02.jpg if he/she login

Problem:

Now, I am currently want try to remake this project on Amazon Web  Services (AWS). I am currently using `AWS Cognito` which in my understanding is equal to `Firebase Authentication` & `AWS S3 Storage` which in my understanding is equal to `Firebase Storage`.

I am still confuse how to develop with AWS, but i think i already manage how to get the `userId` (or `sub` i think in AWS Cognito) if the user login

I try to recreate the `Firabase Storage Rules` with https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html for `S3 Bucket Policy`but there is no condition like only this `userId` (or `sub` i think in AWS Cognito) allow to READ his/her private files.

I am new to this Firebase and very new to this AWS things. Please guide me throughly, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use an Amazon S3 Bucket Policy, nor should you put S3 permissions on the user themselves.

Instead, it should work as follows:

- The Amazon S3 bucket should be kept **private** (no Bucket Policy)
- When a user accesses a web page in your application that wants to **show or link to** one of the S3 files, the application should:

  - Verify that the user is entitled to access the file
  - If so, generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which grants time-limited access to a private object

This way, it is the **application that determines access** and this is done on any page that references/links to a private object. Generating a pre-signed URL only take a couple of lines of code and does *not* require an API call back to Amazon S3.

**For example:** Imagine a **photo-sharing website**. Photos should be private by default (no access). If a user logs-in and wants to view a photo online, the application that generates the HTML page would use an `<img src=...>` tag, but the URL will be a **pre-signed URL**. This means the web browser will display the image on the page. Similarly, if there is a download link to the image, the URL should be a pre-signed URL. Also, users might choose to **share a picture** with another user. Such information would be kept in a database. When another user wants to view the shared image, the application would check the database, verify the permission, then provide a pre-signed URL. This moves the "ownership" away from the path (where the image is stored) and into the **database**.

I'm not a Firebase user, so I don't know what capabilities it has, but the above is the recommended way to manage user access to private files in S3.

Comment: I use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/getting-started_basic-usage.html). I make the PHP on my web host to request the file from my S3 bucket. Through trial and error i manage to make it! Thank you so much

Comment: What i now confuse about the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY must on env HOME, how i set it on my host?
But i found you can explicitly provide credentials to the client [error credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49806405/cannot-read-credentials-from-aws-credentials-php-script-call-aws-sdk) i change `Route53` to `S3`, not sure if it is secure or not.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are asking. Feel free to create a new Question with more details.