# How to use AWS PHP SDK v3.0, without credential file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Hi I am using **aws SDK Version 3** for php to upload files on s3
I need to get rid of credentials file ( .aws/credentials) because it's causing issues on my production server,

The hard coded credentials method isn't working in my code. link pasted below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html#hardcoded-credentials

kindly provide a valid and working solution how to use hard coded credentials.
please note if i use credential file everything works OK. so the problem is with credentials code.

here is my code when I initiate my s3 object

```
$s3Client = new S3Client([
                    'profile' => 'default',
                    'region' => 'us-west-2',
                    'version' => '2006-03-01',
                    'scheme'  => 'http',
                    'credentials'=>[
                        'key' => KEY,
                        'secret' => SECRET
                    ]
                ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to remove the `'profile' => 'default',` line, which has the effect of overriding your hard-coded credentials.

I've been dealing with your same problem with much frustration today, and finally solved it. See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337364/cant-pass-my-credentials-to-aws-php-sdk) here for the same problem on a different Amazon service.

Answer (score 0):

per AWS documentation, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html

> If you do not provide credentials to a client object at the time of
>   its instantiation (e.g., via the client's factory method or via a
>   service builder configuration), the SDK will attempt to find
>   credentials in your environment when you call your first operation.
>   The SDK will use the $_SERVER superglobal and/or getenv() function to
>   look for the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment
>   variables. These credentials are referred to as environment
>   credentials.

Comment: have you guys ever tried this documentation?? its not working at all.at least test the code first before putting your answers as guess here.

Answer (score 0):

V3 doc here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html
In my case I am using an IAM role in the machines which host the app, it is easier to manage permissions from IAM dashboard and you will avoid hardcoded or config file with credentials.